# grunt-contrib-copy - Copy HTML file from ROOT to DIST folder with different assets path

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify, grunt-contrib-concat, grunt-contrib-copy

I am trying to copy HTML file from ROOT folder to DIST folder and that HTML will be minified. I've already achieved that so far.

Now, when the HTML files is being copied to DIST folder, I want to change the INCLUDE path within all included CSS and SCRIPTS.

Is it possible. I went through lot of search on tech forums and so but couldn't find anywhere.

Below is sample code:

```
'use strict';
 
/**
 * Grunt Module
 */
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
          pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
          
          sass: {
        dist: {
          options: {
            style: 'expanded',
            compass: true,
            sourcemap: false
          },
          files: {
            'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.styles.css': ['sass/**/*.scss']
          }
        }
      },
      
      concat: {
        dist: {
          src: ['scripts/**/*.js'],
          dest: 'dist/js/<%= pkg.name %>.scripts.js'
        }
      },
      
      uglify: {
         dist: {
            options: {
               sourceMap: false,
               banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
            },
            files: {
               'dist/js/<%= pkg.name %>.scripts.min.js': ['dist/js/<%= pkg.name %>.scripts.js']
            }
         }
      },
      
      cssmin: {
        minify: {
          src: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.styles.css',
          dest: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.styles.min.css'
        }
      },
      
      htmlmin: {
        dist: {
          options: {
            removeComments: true,
            collapseWhitespace: true
          },
          files: {
            'dist/index.html': 'index.html'
          }
        }
      },
    
      copy: {
        main: {
          files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '/',
            src: '**/*.html',
            dest: 'dist/',
            filter: 'isFile',
            rename: function (dest, src) {
              // Change the path name utilize underscores for folders
              return dest + src.replace(/\//g,'_');
            }
          }],
        }
      },
      
      clean: {
        dist: ['dist/']
      },
      
        watch: {
            sass: {
                files: '**/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass']
            },
            copy:{
              files: '**/*.html',
                tasks: ['sass']
            }
        }
    });
    
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-htmlmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    
    grunt.registerTask('default',['clean', 'sass', 'concat', 'uglify', 'cssmin', 'htmlmin', 'watch']);
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `cwd: '/'` does not look right. The file system root? Are you sure?

Comment: I also tried out by putting SRC for `cwd` but didn't work

Comment: Do I need to add all tasks under `watch: {}`?

Comment: The only solution I want to replace path inside copied HTML file from ROOT to DIST folder!